# Get-ChildItem and registry key access not allowed

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to do a simple PowerShell script to access the registry and I'm doing it like this:

```
Foreach ($key in Get-Childitem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\"{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}") {
    $key.name
}
```

There's a bunch of keys that are just digits (the ones I want) but then there's one named "Properties" which I don't have access (I don't need to) and that key is giving me the following error executing the Foreach command:

```
Foreach ($key in Get-Childitem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\"{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}") {
    $key.name
}
Get-ChildItem : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At line:3 char:31
+ Foreach ($key in Get-Childitem <<<<  HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\"{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}") {
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...318}\Properties:String) [Get-ChildItem], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0001
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0002
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0003
(...)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0024
```

How can I exclude the "Properties" key and get rid of that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just don't want to "see" the error then use the `-ErrorAction` on Get-ChildItem e.g.:

```
$path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\" +
        "{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"
Get-Childitem $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Foreach {$_.Name}
```

The `SilentlyContinue` value tells PowerShell not to display this non-terminating error.  If you want to have PowerShell actually display the value for this key, you'll have to adjust the perms on the registry key.

Comment: No, I don't need that key at all, I just want to ignore it. I noticed and -Exclude argument for Get-ChildItem but wasn't able to use it (didn't work). Hiding the error solves it, but isn't there a way to filter/exclude what I don't want so the error does not show too? It makes more sense to me...

Comment: I think `-Exclude` won't work because Get-ChildItem probably attempts to read the path spec first and then exclude matching items from the cmdlet's output (by then the UnauthorizedAccessException has already occurred).